# Microcontroller to allow or block DC current based on low voltage DC trigger and time-out

Tags: microcontroller, capacitor, relay

Apologies if this has been asked before, but i couldn't find anything, thought that may be due to my lack of understanding of the terminology.

I wish to know if a microcontroller can do this, and if so what i need to look for to find one.

I'm trying to use my Turn-Signal to Trigger a side view camera, but need to somehow convert the pulsing flow from post blinker into a steady flow.

My reading so far indicates a capacitor wouldn't be able to do this effectively, though if it could and i misunderstand that would be ideal.

My though is to set up a microcontroller that upon reviving a pulse of power from the blinker could somehow allow power from a 12V DC connection that by-passes the blinker, through into my camera set-up and stop that power flow if it dose not receive a trigger pulse after a set amount of time, so that it would shut off once the turn signal stops blinking.

I thought of using a Relay to act as the switch, but was unsure how to find, or if one even if one existed, that could be switched on by the pulse and be maintained by the small amount of power that passes the resistor in the blinker in between contacts, again if such a thing is available that would greatly simplify this task, but it seems as of now a microcontroller is the only way to go.

Hopefully someone will know the answer, and sorry if my explanation is unclear or my question is a simplistic one, i am new to this kind of work, and i don't know enough to know what i don't know or need to learn.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance,
~Lin

Comment: they make "timer relay module"s that stay on for an adjustable period after the last activation, that's your simplest bet. you can use an MCU, but you have to be careful about interacting with the 12v. you can use a mosfet like a relay in DC systems

Comment: @linesey: Can you tell us a little more about the camera module. If it has a 12 V electronic 'enable' input then a simple resistor - capacitor time delay will do fine. Link to datasheet?

Comment: I can't find the data sheet but here is the amazon link to the camera, https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01G08MGCA/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 it seems that a Timer relay will work, studying that now.

Comment: The link says, *"Connect the camera power cables to your side lights 12V as automatic trigger."* I'd say they mean "indicators" and that the trigger and time delay are built in.

Comment: @Transitor: I would have thought that would work but it only produced a blinking camera, thought that could be due to the other parts of my setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any help would be much appreciated

I'd use a re-triggerable monostable: -

[image]

There are plenty of circuits on-line such as [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=retriggerable+monostable&sa=X&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ved=0ahUKEwist8iK6LfUAhWD8RQKHcCaCFkQsAQILA&biw=1134&bih=940#imgrc=_)

Comment: That seems like it will work well to, apparently i didn't do enough base research and missed this as a possibility, thank you much, i now have a few avenues to explore.